# How can I access the SQL connection from a bean in a Camel route?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm inserting data into multiple tables, and I use the mybatis component to do that. I also need to create a temporary table before I can insert the data. High-level overview is:

1. Get data to insert
2. Create temp table
3. Insert data to temp table
4. Insert into table1 select x from temp table
5. Insert into table2 select y from temp table

Steps 2 to 5 should be their own single transaction, in case something fails. I've got this currently:

```
from(initialEndpoint)
        .routeId("database-appender")
        .aggregate().expression(constant(true)).completionSize(100).aggregationStrategy(new LinkListAggregator())
        .transacted()
            .bean(CreateTmpLinksTable.class)
            .to("mybatis:prepareLinks?executorType=reuse&statementType=InsertList")
            .to("mybatis:insertLinks?executorType=reuse&statementType=InsertList")
            .to("mybatis:insertLinkSources?executorType=reuse&statementType=InsertList")
        .end()
        .log("Wrote at most ${body.size} links to the database")
```

The CreateTmpLinksTable needs to have access to the current connection, such that the creation of the temporary table does not happen in a different transaction (targeting PostgreSQL, if it matters).

I have this currently:

```
public class CreateTmpLinksTable {
    public void createImportTable(Exchange exchange) throws SQLException {
        final Connection conn = exchange.getIn().getHeader("TransactionConnection", Connection.class);
        try (final Statement stat = conn.createStatement()) {
            stat.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_links(" +
                    "url text, hostname text, service media, service_id bigint, user_id bigint, screen_name text, harvested_at timestamp with time zone, body text" +
                    ") ON COMMIT DROP");
        }
    }
}
```

I also haven't setup my transaction manager. My suspicion is I have to get hold of the transaction manager, in order to correctly participate in the transaction.

Questions:

1. How do I get the transaction manager from a regular bean? Is it just a matter of getting the context, then from the context getting the manager through the registry?
2. Is there a better way to do what I need? I can see at least one: move all responsibilities into a single bean and do the work there. Any other ways?

NOTE: I'm learning Camel, and I like to do things using only code. Once I know how everything is wired up, then I can transfer that knowledge to Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1, 
If you can pass the instance of bean to the camel route, you can setup the transaction manager yourself, otherwise you have to use the registry to look up the transaction manager instance.

Q2,
You can wrap the DB update work in a single bean and use the transacted DSL in camel if you have other resources need to be managed.

Comment: I ended up moving all code within the same bean. I did not need transacted routes, so that's one less complexity.